# How to parse time of ISO timestamp in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can a ISO datetime `String` timestamp be correctly parsed to `time` type column in `mysql`? I noticed the following:

`select CAST('2013-09-05T10:10:02' as time) from mytable limit 1`

Result incorrect:
`00:20:13`

`select CAST(CAST('2013-09-05T10:10:02' as datetime) as time) from mytable limit 1`

Result correct: 
`10:10:02`

Why do I have to make a double `CAST` here to get the correct time? And more important: how is time parsing done property?

Answer (score 1):

Basically when you try to convert something to a time that looks like an integer MySQL treats that as something in the form `HHMMSS`, so your `2013-09-05T10:10:02` becomes `00:20:13`. To convert properly, the value needs to be a MySQL `datetime`, which you can do via `CAST` or you can use [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert your date string to a MySQL date, then [`TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) to extract the time part of it:

```
SELECT TIME(STR_TO_DATE('2013-09-05T10:10:02', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s'))
```

Output:

```
10:10:02
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cdd9e24738f93efd0af3325950f3027d)

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a string which you need to first cast it into date format.

If you cast it in time like below:

```
   select CAST('2014-09-05T10:10:02' as time)
    00:20:14
    select CAST('2015-09-05T10:10:02' as time)
    00:20:15


  select CAST('2013' as time) --below casting string as time
    00:20:13
```

If you monitor closely its treating it as string and getting year as time.

So you need to cast it datetime first then time.

```
select CAST(CAST('2013-09-05T10:10:02' as datetime) as time)
```